# When doing degugs in Visual Studio(C#), Is there a way to insert a line of code after breakpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, pry

I am now debugging an MVC ASP.net project. After I set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and run the project, it stops at the breakpoint as I expect. But I need to add some lines while debugging.

Is there any when to do so. I want it runs like debugging Ruby on Rails project with Pry.

Comment: You can run most code (No lamba expressions at least) from the immediate window while stopped at a break point. If you don't have the window in the Views list, open the command window and type 'immed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what the code needs to be prior to compilation, you could use a block similar to this

```
#if DEBUG 
  // Do Debug
#endif
```

This will only execute if debugging the code.  Allowing you to do certain things if debug else dont run that code.

We use it to allow us to launch new debuggers for threads other than the main application thread for example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about older versions, but Visual Studio 2013 supports it. However, it can get a bit tricky with certain things such as adding new variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it on VS 2012 and 2013, I am not sure about other versions.To edit will debugging you have to enable editing which is in tools => options =>debugging =>edit and continue.

Comment: Note that (in VS 2012 at least) this only works if the program is running as a 32-bit process.  Edit and continue is not available for 64-bit processes.